# Expresión regular para negar las letras en QlineEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pyqt

Estoy generando una calculadora con un *QlineEdit*.

Quiero utilizar una expresión regular para negar las letras y que solo acepte números y símbolos. Para ello ocupé la siguiente sintaxis.

```
self.regexp = QtCore.QRegExp('^[a-z]') #Expresion para eliminar letras
self.validador= QtGui.QRegExpValidator(self.regexp)
self.lineEdit.setValidator(self.validador)
```

pero no funciona. Hasta donde he podido entender lo que estoy haciendo es negando todas las letras en el line edit.

¿Qué es lo que me falta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Clase de caracteres negada:**

```
[^caracteres]
```

*Coincide con 1 (y sólo 1) caracter, cualquier caracter que no esté listado en la clase.*

---

Un `^` fuera de una clase de caracteres coincide con la posición inicial del string (o de la línea si se usa el modificador [*multiline*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M)).

Dentro de una clase de caracteres, si aparece como primer caracter, niega a la clase. **Ejemplos:**

1. cualquier caracter que no sea una letra de la `a` a la `z` (coincide con un número por ejemplo)

   ```
   [^a-z]
   ```
2. un string que no tenga ninguna letra (`a` a `z`); buscamos desde el inicio del string hasta el final

   ```
   ^[^a-z]*$
   ```

   - En este caso, el primer `^` coincide con el inicio del texto, y el segundo niega a la clase de caracteres en la que está. Luego se repite ese carácter `[^a-z]` 0 o más veces con el `*`, hasta que coincida con el final del texto `$`.
3. que tampoco tenga mayúsculas

   ```
   ^[^A-Za-z]*$
   ```

O sin negar la clase de caracteres, coincidiendo desde el inicio del string hasta el final:

4. que sólo tenga números y algunos signos

   ```
   ^[-+*/()\[\].\d]*$
   ```
5. lo mismo, también con espacios

   ```
   ^[-+*/()\[\].\d ]*$
   ```

   - y conviene pasarlo como literal para no escapar las barras: `r"^[-+*/()\[\].\d ]*$"`

Por otro lado, un `^` dentro de una clase de caracteres que no es el primer caracter, se interpreta como literal. Tanto `[qt^]` como `[\^qt]` coinciden con uno de esos 3 caracteres.

---

Al estar usando [**QRegExpValidator**](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qregexpvalidator.html), se agregan 2 cosas:

1. La idea no es reemplazar los caracteres inválidos, sino coincidir con un string válido.
2. No hay que anclar el regex al inicio ni al fin del string, porque el propio método lo verifica para que sea [`Acceptable`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qvalidator.html#State-enum).

```py
QRegExp(r"[-+*/()\[\].\d ]*")
```

Lo interesante de [QRegExpValidator](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qregexpvalidator.html) es con las coincidencias parciales. Si usaras una expresión más compleja, por ejemplo:

- que empiece con un número, y tenga cualquier cantidad de operadores seguidos de números:

  ```py
  \d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[-+*/ ]+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*
  ```

te permitiría distinguir entre

- [*Acceptable*](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qvalidator.html#State-enum) (coincidencias completas).
  Ejemplo: `"12 * 3.45 + 6"`
- [*Intermediate*](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qvalidator.html#State-enum) (coincidencias parciales o incompletas, que de tener más caracteres en el input, *podrían* coincidir).
  Ejemplo: `"12 * 3.45 + "`
- [*Invalid*](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qvalidator.html#State-enum). Ejemplos: `"12.34.55"`, `"12 - 34 56"`, `12+34w-56`.